# Update Component Even If SelectOneMenu Value Is Required

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a required select and my problem is that when the user selects an empty option (null) the validation jumps in and the listener call of the select is being skipped. Some components on my view are depending on this value so in case of null being selected the bean won't get actualized and the components don't change.

Example:

```
<h:form id="createForm">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="produktCreateTypSelect"
            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter"
            value="#{productController.selectedProduct.typ}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- Select --" />
        <f:selectItems var="productType" value="#{productController.findAllProducts()}"
                itemLabel="#{productType.name}" itemValue="#{productType}" />
        <p:ajax process="@this " event="valueChange" update="createForm"
                listener="#{productController.printHelloWorld}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:panelGroup id="dummy1" rendered="#{productController.selectedProduct.type != null}" />
</h:form>
```

The question is what the best way is to update that panelGroup

> 'dummy1'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use update=":createForm:dummy1" to update the panelGroup

Comment: If you want the empty value also to be submitted, you will have to remove the required attribute.

Comment: @OTM Aws ok... Aren't there any alternatives without removing the required attribute?

Comment: When you have required="true" you will have to select a value to be submitted. In case if you need to do application specific validation you could create and go for a custom validator.